# Adding a check for null object in JVM bytecode

Tags: jvm, bytecode

I'm using ASM to modify the bytecode of any java class to add a null-check for each object.

For example, for this piece of code:

```
Object a = new Object();
a.doSomething();
```

I want to modify the bytecode so it looks like this:

```
Object a = new Object();
assertNotNull(a);
a.doSomething();
```

or this:

```
Object a = new Object();
if(a != null){
a.doSomething();}
else return 1 //or throw exception
```

I'm stuck because I don't know what number go with ALOAD. I think ALOAD always go with ALOAD 1 (or in this format ALOAD n). What can I do to get the number that goes with ALOAD? Here's my work so far (using Junit assertNotNull)

```
/*
 * Use JUnit assertNotNull to check object/item for null
 */
private void addAssertNullMethod() {
    //need to add ALOAD here, but I don't know the location of the object on the stack.
    mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "org/junit/Assert", "assertNull", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V", false);
    mv.visitEnd();
}
```

Comment: You didn’t show your program logic to decide when to invoke `addAssertNullMethod()`. When you invoke it right before the other member access, [apangin’s answer applies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49715193/2711488), the value will be on the operand stack. But regardless of where you call it, invoking `mv.visitEnd();` in the middle of the method is never correct. And by the way, I can’t recognize the purpose of this instrumentation. You’re just replacing the `NullPointerException` with another exception. Further, your “assertNotNull” of your question’s text has become `assertNull` in the code…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `DUP` bytecode instead.

`ALOAD` refers to local variables, but there can be be no local variable slot assigned for a given object. Before calling `doSomething()`, an object reference is already put on the expression stack (with `ALOAD` bytecode or some other - it does not matter). So all you need is to copy this object reference (with `DUP`) and then invoke your assert method.